# Eclipselink Workbench - Identiy column

Tags: java, database, eclipselink, identity

we are working with the eclipselink workbench to generate java persistence objects to our eclipse projects. 
We have some tables with identity columns and found no option to tell eclipselink that this column is a identiy column. We found thousends of hints where annotations of jpa solve that problem but we generate our deployment.xml with the workbench and use no annotations:

[Eclipse link jpa documentation](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Introduction_to_EclipseLink_JPA_(ELUG)#.40GeneratedValue)

Does anybody know how to handle with it?

Comment: You will have to look at the documentation for the workbench tool, but it is used for creating native EclipseLink projects mappings and xml files, and can be used for generating the schema and java objects from those mappings.  It predates JPA though, so will not create JPA entities.

Comment: I found nothing in the documentation of the workbench but can not imagine that is not possible to define that some columns are database identity columns. Hopefully someone has the right hint.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution of my own. Hopefully someone will help this in few seconds (not few days like me).

**1. Enable the native sequencing in your session object
(Tab Login => Options => native sequencing)**

**2. Know navigate to your generated java obect and select the descriptor tab.**

**3. Enable Sequencing. Take your primary key and write down "IDENTITY" as Name.**

Test it and be happy. puh.

[Native sequencing - non oralcle db](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Introduction_to_Relational_Projects_(ELUG)#Native_Sequencing_with_a_Non-Oracle_Database_Platform)